# Batch command to select multiple file and output it as single line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I tried to find a many way to finish this but still no hope ( tried with array etc ...)

Is there a way that I can select part of the file listed in the dir and output it as below

for example if I input 0-2, it output as

```
00000\.MTS+00001.MTS+00002.MTS
```

same , if I input 3-5,

```
00003\.MTS+00004.MTS+00005.MTS
```

EXAMPLE FOLDER LIST

```
2022-03-24  00:14    \<DIR\>          .
2022-03-24  00:14    \<DIR\>          ..
2022-03-23  15:47         5,025,792 00000.MTS
2022-03-23  15:47         4,958,208 00001.MTS
2022-03-23  15:47         3,938,304 00002.MTS
2022-03-23  15:47         9,185,280 00003.MTS
2022-03-23  15:48         9,179,136 00004.MTS
2022-03-23  15:48         3,028,992 00005.MTS
```

---

The reason I try to do this it is because I would like to join the MTS files without typing in one by one in the command. The original command is like

```
copy /b 00000.MTS+00001.MTS+00002.MTS+00003.MTS+00004.MTS+00005.MTS "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\1.MTS"
```

Hope I can use the batch command
1st : 0-2

```
copy /b 00000.MTS+00001.MTS+00002.MTS "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\1.MTS"
```

2nd : 3-5

```
copy /b 00003.MTS+00004.MTS+00005.MTS "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\2.MTS"
```

Is it possible to complete this in bat ?

I did try with the for loop to gen the file list,

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /P "mts1=MTS SET 1 : "
for %%n in (%mts1%) do (
echo !FILE_LIST\[%%n\]!+
)
```

but seem it only show all and also every file uses a new line, cannot be use in copy /b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory and destination directory are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"
SET "destdir=%sourcedir%"

:: Do we have 2 arguments?
IF "%~2" equ "" ECHO need 2 arguments&GOTO :eof

:: calculate the destination filename
SET /a destfile=0
:destloop
SET /a destfile+=1
IF EXIST "%destdir%\%destfile%.MTS" GOTO destloop

:: change to source directory
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

:: then build the list of files to concatenate
SET "sourcelist="
:again
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d /on 0*.MTS ') DO (
 SET "candidate="
 SET /a candidate=1%%~nb 2>NUL
 IF DEFINED candidate (
  SET /a serial=candidate -100000
  IF !serial! geq %1 IF !serial! leq %2 SET "sourcelist=!sourcelist!+%%~nxb"
  IF !SERIAL! GEQ %2 IF "%3" NEQ "" SHIFT&SHIFT&GOTO AGAIN

 )
)
IF DEFINED sourcelist COPY %sourcelist:~1% "%destdir%\%destfile%.MTS"   >nul
:: back to original directory
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

First step: get the destination filename by incrementing a counter and seeing whether that filename already exists.

Next: scan a basic directory list of the `.MTS` filenames that start `0`. For each candidate found, set `candidate` to *empty* then attempt to user an arithmetic `set` (`set /a`) string `1` in front so that the number becomes, eg `100000`. This is because numbers that start `0` are considered as octal by `cmd`. If the resultant string is not numeric, the `set /a` will fail, an error message will be produced (the `2>nul` suppresses the error message) and `candidate` will remain set to *empty*, ie. undefined.

If `candidate` is defined, then subtract the 100000 that was added in, and check whether the result is greater than or equal to the first parameter AND less than or equal to the second parameter. If so, build `sourcelist` with the new name preceded by `+`.

Finally, do the copy using substringing to drop the leading `+` from `sourcelist`.

Run the batch with two parameters, the start and end numbers, eg. `thisbatch 3 7`

---

Amendment in response to comment:

Insert the label `:again` and add the extra line `IF !serial! geq %2...`

When the first range is ended, set `serial` to the current 3rd argument. If `serial` is now defined, shift out the first two arguments and start over, with `sourcelist` already part-built.

Note that this allows any pairs to be used, so `thisbatch 12 15 3 6` is valid, as is `thisbatch 12 14 3 7 6 11`

--- Small revision

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory and destination directory are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"
SET "destdir=%sourcedir%"

:: Do we have 2 arguments?
IF "%~2" equ "" ECHO need 2 arguments&GOTO :eof

:restart
:: calculate the destination filename
SET /a destfile=0
:destloop
SET /a destfile+=1
IF EXIST "%destdir%\%destfile%.MTS" GOTO destloop

:: change to source directory
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

:: then build the list of files to concatenate
SET "sourcelist="
:again
IF /i "%1"=="E" GOTO docopy
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d /on 0*.MTS ') DO (
 SET "candidate="
 SET /a candidate=1%%~nb 2>NUL
 IF DEFINED candidate (
  SET /a serial=candidate -100000
  IF !serial! geq %1 IF !serial! leq %2 SET "sourcelist=!sourcelist!+%%~nxb"
  IF !SERIAL! GEQ %2 IF "%3" NEQ "" SHIFT&SHIFT&GOTO AGAIN
 )
)
:docopy
IF DEFINED sourcelist COPY %sourcelist:~1% "%destdir%\%destfile%.MTS"   >nul
:: back to original directory
POPD
IF /i "%1"=="E" shift&GOTO restart

GOTO :EOF
```

This gives you the best of both worlds.

If you have a command line `thisbatch 3 6 0 2` then it will generate 1 new file with 3+4+5+6+0+1+2.

If you have a command line `thisbatch 3 6 0 2 E 12 15 0 2 E 1 4` then it will generate 3 new files with 3+4+5+6+0+1+2, 12+13+14+15+0+1+2 and 1+2+3+4.

The names for each number-pair are concatenated as before. If the next "start number" is `E` (either case) then the `copy` command is executed, the `E` is shifted out and the entire process restarted with arguments of whatever was beyond the `E` by returning to the label with the bizarre name `:restart`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Magoo i will come back to vote this up ! 
---
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Answer (score -1):

This can be used at a `cmd` prompt or in a `batch-file` script. The `function` builds an array of desired numbers. The desired numbers are expressed as a string similar to many applications specifying page numbers (ie: "1-3" or "3-5,7,10-12")

Place the `Do-ConcatFiles.bat` and `Do-ConcatFiles.ps1` script in the same directory. If you are on a supported `windows` system, PowerShell is available.

=== Do-ConcatFiles.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dpDo-ConcatFiles.ps1" -PagesList 1-3,12 -Path ".\pageslist.txt"
```

=== Do-ConcatFiles.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$PagesList = '1-3,5,7-12'

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Path = 'C:\src\t\pageslist\pageslist.txt'
)
function Get-PagesList([string]$PagesString) {
# Build an array of desired numbers.
$Pages = @()
$PagesString -replace '\s*' -split ',' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '(\d*)\-(\d*)') {
            for ([int]$i = [int]$Matches[1]; $i -le [int]$Matches[2]; $i++) { $Pages += $i }
        } else { $Pages += $_ }
    }
return $Pages
}

<#  TEST FILE GENERATION
1..20 | ForEach-Object {
    $FileName = ('{0:000000}' -f $_) + '.txt'
    Set-Content -Path $FileName -Value $FileName -Encoding ascii
}
#>

Write-Verbose "Input PagesList = $PagesList"
Write-Verbose "Input result file is $Path"
$Pages = Get-PagesList($PagesList)
if ($Pages.Count -ne 0) {
    if (Test-Path -Path $Path) { Remove-Item -Path $Path }
    $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path '[0-9]*.txt'
    $Pages |
        ForEach-Object {
            foreach ($File in $Files) {
                if (($File -match '(\d*).txt') -and ([int]$Matches[1] -eq $_)) {
                    Write-Verbose "Appending file $File to $Path"
                    Get-Content -Path $File | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Append -Encoding ascii
                }
            }
        }
}
```